# how to add bot avatar in bot framework v4 in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, botframework, chatbot

I have created a chatbot using Microsoft Bot Framework v4 in C#, I am looking for ways to add avatar to the bot.

I am not able to find any documentation online to do so in c#. i do see documentation for this in node js (Web Chat).

is it even possible in c#? has anyone done this before?

thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JySn6.png)

looks like its possible in node js but I cant find anything for c#

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be a little confused by the concept of backend and frontend. The C# code is the backend. Avatars for the bot on webchat are specified on the front end, which is written javascript. So if you want to update the avatars, you're going to have to write javascript for the web page you're rendering the chat on, as per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-webchat-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

If you're talking about avatars on something other than the web chat, can you specify which channel you're looking at?

Comment: Thank you, but after i deployed my code to azure bot server it provides me with an iframe which i am using in windows pop up in my application. i am not sure how can i write JS to control/style bot from iframe